# onReceived, how to continue inside same Activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

what would be the best way to continue the current Activity once its internal BroadcastReceiver onReceived has been called.

is it possible to start another thread from within the onReceived() method, and also can I start a AsyncTask inside the onReceived() ?

is it possible to start the same activity again from within the onReceived method?

thanx

Comment: `what would be the best way to continue the current Activity once its internal BroadcastReceiver onReceived has been called.` ......>  Does it closes the activity when onReceived called????

Comment: no, but I want some logic to be called again inside the same Activity?

Comment: create a method in your activity with your logic and call it from onRecevied ?!

Comment: hi Gal, my problem is my broadcast receiver is a inner class and needs to be defined as static otherwise it wont work

Comment: this is the exception I am getting:  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.inetkey.ConfigurationActivity$MyReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.inetkey.ConfigurationActivity$MyReceiver; no empty constructor

Comment: and this is how I have declared it inside manifest:  <receiver android:name=".ConfigurationActivity$MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.inetkey.CUSTOM_INTENT">

        </action>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Answer (score 0):

Please note that an Activity does not survive a screen orientation change -- it gets re-created along with the View hierarchy. From the MVC viewpoint, an Activity is a Controller. Data that must survive an orientation change must go to the Model.

If you keep a reference to the Activity that has gone from the screen due to orientation change, that's a resource leak, and if the Activity receives the result of some AsyncTask, that's also a waste of CPU time and battery power.

Having said that, Activity defines *runOnUiThread (Runnable action)* which most likely is not what you really need, but it will at least work.

I mean, after the receiver's method is called, the normal cycle continues (reaction on events etc.), so you just need to react on the event reported to your BroadcastReceiver and reach the closing brace of the function.

If you ask if you can rely on that the same instance of SomeActivity will be shown when a long operation completes, the answer is no. For example, the user starts a long operation, then changes the screen orientation. The first SomeActivity, the one that started the long operation, will not be shown when the long operation completes.